# sending mail using external smtp from container

Tags: email, docker, smtp

I prepared an app that can send mail through `smtp.gmail.com` and it works well but, when I run it using docker, I get an error - as it can't connect to `smtp.gmail.com`. The function sending mails is:

```
public void sendEmal(String body, String mailRecipient){
   Properties props = new Properties();
   props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
   props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
   props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
   props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
   props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
   try{
        Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);
        mailSession.setDebug(true);
        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        message.setContent(body, "text/plain");
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
        new InternetAddress("mailRecipient"));

        transport.connect();
        transport.sendMessage(message,
        message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        transport.close();  
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

This is the error:

> myapp_thirdInst    | DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host
>   "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false
>
> myapp_thirdInst    | javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host:
>   smtp.gmail.com;
>
> myapp_thirdInst    |   nested exception is:
>
> myapp_thirdInst    |  java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com
>
> myapp_thirdInst    | error sending mail

It's the first time I'm playing with docker and after some tries, it continues to fail. I'm kind of lost - could anyone give me a hint to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you post what your container base image is? I've seen ultra small ones in the past which were built on top of a container with uclibc as the resolver library and it was completely faulty, it would fail 90 out of 100 DNS requests but worked randomly

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is get DNS working! Test the container DNS first with a shell, get that working and then your SMTP code may work.

Perhaps you can update your question with information about your DNS configuration

Comment: exactly, thanks!!! I added the host dns to my docker-compose and it started working :). Now I am investigating the way to get the host dns dynamically as I want to run this app in different hosts without having to set the ip manually... I guess that should be possible??

Comment: Usually docker creates a DNS config(resolve.conf) in a subdirectory in /var/lib/docker for each container, and creates a volume mapping to map that file to /etc/resolve.conf inside the container. Not sure why that wouldn't be working but you can maybe do it manually by adding docker flags '-v /etc/resolv.conf:/etc/resolve.conf', which I assume you could add into the compose file in the 'volumes' area. This may help: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23910

Comment: Thanks Chunko, very interesting post! reading it the conclussion seems to be "you can do it this way but it is not the perfect solution and it needs manual stuff". Then if I want my application to be totally free of manual configuration, then, should I implement my own DNS server in a separate container? I suppose in that way I wouldn't need the host dns and then no configuration would be needed every time I run the container.